# How to use ajax in oracle adf using jdeveloper?

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to use an ajax method in jedeveloper jsp page just like the below example. How can i achieve it ?

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: myBean.someMethod,
   success: function(responseData)
   {
      var dt = responseData.toString();
   },
   error: function(msg) {
          var dt = msg.toString();
          alert(dt);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use your own AJAX code in ADF. ADF is already using a lot of AJAX; your own code is likely to interfere with ADF standard functionality, leading to hard-to-find errors.

What are you trying to achieve? There is surely and ADF way of doing it.

Comment: I want to show the change in some fields without page refreshing . I used partial triggers. Is there any better approach ?

Comment: Partial triggers is the correct approach; you only need to set the property on the fields you want to refresh to point to the UI element that should trigger the refresh. That's all declarative with none of your own JS involved